How to pickel (save model object) a Google or-tool's mathopt model object
I am building a model using mathopt library of or tools, and I want to save the model object as a pickle file (or any other suitable alternative). The use case for doing this is - underlying data behind the model build is huge, and it takes some time to build the model, however, when user interacts with the model, he/she will change only a couple of constraints at the maximum. So, I wanted to a) save the model object, and then b) load it back in memory, c) identify the constraint the user wants to change, and then update only that constraint, d) run the revised model and solve. Do the same process for multiple calls by user
However, pickling somehow is not working with mathopt:
from ortools.math_opt.python import mathopt

model = mathopt.Model(name="getting_started_lp")
x = model.add_variable(lb=0.0, ub=1.5, name="x")
y = model.add_variable(lb=0.0, ub=1.0, name="y")
model.add_linear_constraint(x + y <= 2)
model.maximize(x + 2 * y)

# try to pickle the model object
pickle.dumps(model)

# get the below error
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'WeakSet.__init__.<locals>._remove'

Pickle seems to work with cp-sat solver though:
model = cp_model.CpModel()
x = model.new_int_var(0, 10, "x")
y = model.new_int_var(0, 10, "y")
model.add(2 * x + 7 * y <= 20)
model.maximize(2 * x + 2 * y)
b = pickle.dumps(model)
# runs without any errors

Is there any way out - any alternative to saving the model for later use with mathopt ?
------ BELOW IS MY ATTEMPT TO SAVE THE MATHOPT MODEL --------
But does not work
from google.protobuf import text_format

from ortools.math_opt.python import mathopt

model = mathopt.Model(name="getting_started_lp")
x = model.add_variable(lb=0.0, ub=1.5, name="x")
y = model.add_variable(lb=0.0, ub=1.0, name="y")
model.add_linear_constraint(x + y <= 2)
model.maximize(x + 2 * y)

def export_model(model, filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(text_format.MessageToString(model.export_model()))


def import_model(filename):
    model = mathopt.Model()
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        text_format.Parse(file.read(), model.export_model())
    return model

# runs fine -- exports model
export_model(model, "mdl")

# fails
import_model("mdl")

# ParseError: 1:11 : Message type # "operations_research.math_opt.ModelProto" should not have # multiple "objective" fields.


Why not use protobuf for CP-SAT? It is the native storage format.

Thanks Laurent. If you don't mind could you please show me how to do that through a simple example may be. Many thanks.

If you see my edit in the post, I have made an attempt to save the mathopt model, but clearly I am missing something. Hoping for your able guidance.

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/samples/clone_model_sample_sat.py

Thanks, but I want to export a mathopt model to a file, which I can later import back. Could you please help me with the mathopt model pls. I tried to do in my code, but does not work. Thanks.

I only work on CP-SAT, and only offered advice on CP-SAT.

As Laurent said, I would recommend using proto instead of pickle generically whenever possible.
It appears that pickle won't work at all with mathopt due to the use of weak references.
MathOpt has the function in C++:
Model::FromModelProto()
How to pickel (save model object) a Google or-tool's mathopt model object
Which is what you need, but it is missing from the Python API.
A user wrote this code:
def from_model_proto(model_proto: model_pb2.ModelProto) -> mathopt.Model:
  """Converts a ModelProto of a Mixed-Integer Linear Program to a mathopt.Model.

  This functions builds a minimization problems with linear constraints and
  objective.

  Args:
    model_proto: The ModelProto to convert.

  Returns:
    The converted mathopt.Model.
  """
  model = mathopt.Model(name=model_proto.name)

  # Add variables.
  id_variable_map = {
      model_proto.variables.ids[i]: model.add_variable(
          name=model_proto.variables.names[i]
          if model_proto.variables.names
          else '',
          lb=model_proto.variables.lower_bounds[i],
          ub=model_proto.variables.upper_bounds[i],
          is_integer=model_proto.variables.integers[i],
      )
      for i, _ in enumerate(model_proto.variables.ids)
  }

  # Set objective.
  num_nonzeros_objective = len(model_proto.objective.linear_coefficients.ids)
  model.minimize(
      sum(
          id_variable_map[model_proto.objective.linear_coefficients.ids[i]]
          * model_proto.objective.linear_coefficients.values[i]
          for i in range(num_nonzeros_objective)
      )
  )

  # Set constraints.
  id_constraint_map = {
      model_proto.linear_constraints.ids[j]: model.add_linear_constraint(
          lb=model_proto.linear_constraints.lower_bounds[j],
          ub=model_proto.linear_constraints.upper_bounds[j],
          name=model_proto.linear_constraints.names[j],
      )
      for j, _ in enumerate(model_proto.linear_constraints.ids)
  }

  num_nonzero = len(model_proto.linear_constraint_matrix.column_ids)
  for i in range(num_nonzero):
    var_id = model_proto.linear_constraint_matrix.column_ids[i]
    con_id = model_proto.linear_constraint_matrix.row_ids[i]
    coef = model_proto.linear_constraint_matrix.coefficients[i]
    id_constraint_map[con_id].set_coefficient(id_variable_map[var_id], coef)

  return model

which probably does most of what you want (it doesn't handle as much of the ModelProto as the python API does, e.g. no quadratic objectives). You would need to read the proto from a file, then convert the proto back into a MathOpt model with this code.
A different (and complete) implementation will eventually be merged into mathopt, this is just a stopgap.

Thanks Ross for the prompt reply. This is very helpful. However, for my use case, I need to export my model as a file, and then later read it. So if I write the
model_proto: ortools.math_opt.model_pb2.ModelProto to a file, then how I can read it back as a model_proto back ? At present it just reads it as a raw file.
I am exporting model proto to local drive as follows
file.write(text_format.MessageToString(model.export_model()))
using from google.protobuf import text_format
So the question is - how I can read it back in model_proto format in python. Rest is crystal clear.

@BhartenduAwasthi See protobuf docs on Writing and Reading / Python. The most important code-snippet is probably address_book.ParseFromString(f.read()) aka protobuf gives you a deserialization-function. Imho you should not make it text and keep files in binary (protobuf serialization is by default a binary-format). Don't let the name string fool you as protobuf just uses strings in many language-impls as type for storing RAW bytes aka binary (not displayable in terminal/editor !).

Many thanks, @sascha !
